# How do I add spacing of the icon on right side in the appbar

Tags: flutter

I just started the flutter and here I'm confused how to add the spacing.

Please help me out.

[image]

```
  appBar: AppBar(
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title: Text("Breeds of Dogs"),
          actions: <Widget>[
             Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
          ],  
        )
```

Comment: You need to share your code as text with question

Comment: wrap it with padding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Icon button instead of `icon`,

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Breeds of Dogs'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add_a_photo,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
              print("Hello");
             }),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: How is this answer different from the first one?

Comment: I didn't see the above answer , I just copy my code and pasted here.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IconButton` instead of `Icon`.

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Breeds of Dogs'),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add_a_photo,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {}),
        ],
      ),
```